# Какие советы можно получить по данному JS коду?

Tags: javascript

решил методом практики учить Javascript + его фреймворки.
На тостере посоветовали что для понимания принципов работы React' Angular, требуется написать пару приложений на нативном Javascript. Написал простой To-Do. Я понимаю что много плохого кода, но буду очень признателен если сможете указать на критичные ошибки. Заранее спасибо
https://codepen.io/denibudeyko/pen/MWyEmox

```js
(function(window) {
  'use strict';

  // Initial Const 
  const input = document.getElementsByClassName('new-todo')[0]
  const todoList = document.getElementsByClassName('todo-list')[0]
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list li')
  const clear = document.querySelector('.clear-completed')
  const todoCount = document.querySelector('.todo-count strong')

  // Add new task
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

    var string = input.value;

    if (e.key == 'Enter') {
      const li = document.createElement('li')
      li.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="view">
                        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
                        <label>${string}</label>
                        <button class="destroy"></button>
                    </div>
                    <input class="edit" value="${string}">
                `;

      todoList.appendChild(li);
      const childrenItem = li.querySelector('input.toggle')

      childrenItem.addEventListener('click', event => {
        toggleTaskStatusEvent(event.target)
      })

      input.value = '';
      updateCount();
    }
  })

  function updateCount() {
    todoCount.textContent = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list li:not(.completed)').length;
  }

  updateCount()


  // Toggle Status
  document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list li').forEach(item => {

    const toggleCheckbox = item.querySelector('input.toggle')
    toggleCheckbox.addEventListener('click', event => {
      toggleTaskStatusEvent(event.target)
    })
  })

  // ToggleTaskStatus
  function toggleTaskStatusEvent(e) {
    const liParent = e.closest('li')
    liParent.classList.toggle('completed')
    updateCount()
  }

  clear.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list li.completed').forEach(item => {
      item.remove()
    })
  })

  // FiltersButtons
  document.querySelectorAll('ul.filters li').forEach(item => {
    const filterButton = item.children[0];
    filterButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
      runFilter(event.target)
    })
  })

  // Function Filter
  function runFilter(item) {
    const notCompletedItemsFilter = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list li:not(.completed)')
    const completedItemsFilter = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list li.completed')
    const allItemsFilter = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list li');

    var href = item.getAttribute('href')
    href = href.split('#/')[1]

    const activeButton = document.querySelector('ul.filters a.selected')
    activeButton.classList.remove('selected')
    item.classList.add("selected")

    if (href == 'active') {

      notCompletedItemsFilter.forEach(item => {
        item.style.display = 'block';
      })
      completedItemsFilter.forEach(item => {
        item.style.display = 'none';
      })

    } else if (href == 'completed') {
      notCompletedItemsFilter.forEach(item => {
        item.style.display = 'none';
      })
      completedItemsFilter.forEach(item => {
        item.style.display = 'block';
      })
    } else if (href == 'all') {
      allItemsFilter.forEach(item => {
        item.style.display = 'block'
      })
    }
  }

  // Edit Task Double click
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('dblclick', event => {
      editTask(item)
    })
  })

  // Edit Task
  function editTask(item) {
    var label = item.querySelector('label');
    var editButton = item.querySelector('.edit')
    editButton.style.display = 'block'

    editButton.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      label.textContent = this.value
      if (event.key == 'Enter') {
        this.style.display = 'none';
      }
    })
  }

  // Function Remove Task
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.querySelector('.destroy').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      item.remove()
      updateCount();
    })
  })
})(window);
```

```css
.todo-list li .toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-weight: 300;
}

 :focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.todoapp {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 130px 0 40px 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.todoapp input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

.todoapp input::-moz-placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

.todoapp input::input-placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

.todoapp h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -155px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.15);
  -webkit-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.new-todo,
.edit {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.new-todo {
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 60px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.003);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.toggle-all {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  /* Mobile Safari */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.toggle-all+label {
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -52px;
  left: -13px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.toggle-all+label:before {
  content: '❯';
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 10px 27px 10px 27px;
}

.toggle-all:checked+label:before {
  color: #737373;
}

.todo-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.todo-list li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.todo-list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.todo-list li.editing {
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.todo-list li.editing .edit {
  display: block;
  width: 506px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  margin: 0 0 0 43px;
}

.todo-list li.editing .view {
  display: none;
}

.todo-list li .toggle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  /* auto, since non-WebKit browsers doesn't support input styling */
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  border: none;
  /* Mobile Safari */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.todo-list li .toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.todo-list li .toggle+label {
  /*
            Firefox requires `#` to be escaped - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=922433
            IE and Edge requires *everything* to be escaped to render, so we do that instead of just the `#` - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7157459/
        */
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width%3D%2240%22%20height%3D%2240%22%20viewBox%3D%22-10%20-18%20100%20135%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2250%22%20cy%3D%2250%22%20r%3D%2250%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ededed%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
}

.todo-list li .toggle:checked+label {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width%3D%2240%22%20height%3D%2240%22%20viewBox%3D%22-10%20-18%20100%20135%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2250%22%20cy%3D%2250%22%20r%3D%2250%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22%23bddad5%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22/%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%235dc2af%22%20d%3D%22M72%2025L42%2071%2027%2056l-4%204%2020%2020%2034-52z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}

.todo-list li label {
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 60px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}

.todo-list li.completed label {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.todo-list li .destroy {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #cc9a9a;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

.todo-list li .destroy:hover {
  color: #af5b5e;
}

.todo-list li .destroy:after {
  content: '×';
}

.todo-list li:hover .destroy {
  display: block;
}

.todo-list li .edit {
  display: none;
}

.todo-list li.editing:last-child {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.footer {
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.footer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 8px 0 -3px #f6f6f6, 0 9px 1px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 16px 0 -6px #f6f6f6, 0 17px 2px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.todo-count {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.todo-count strong {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.filters {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.filters li {
  display: inline;
}

.filters li a {
  color: inherit;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.filters li a:hover {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.1);
}

.filters li a.selected {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

.clear-completed,
html .clear-completed:active {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clear-completed:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.info {
  margin: 65px auto 0;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

.info p {
  line-height: 1;
}

.info a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.info a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*
        Hack to remove background from Mobile Safari.
        Can't use it globally since it destroys checkboxes in Firefox
    */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .toggle-all,
  .todo-list li .toggle {
    background: none;
  }
  .todo-list li .toggle {
    height: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 430px) {
  .footer {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .filters {
    bottom: 10px;
  }
}

hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px dashed #c5c5c5;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #f7f7f7;
}

.learn a {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b83f45;
}

.learn a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #787e7e;
}

.learn h3,
.learn h4,
.learn h5 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #000;
}

.learn h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.learn h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.learn h5 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.learn ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px 25px;
}

.learn li {
  line-height: 20px;
}

.learn p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#issue-count {
  display: none;
}

.quote {
  border: none;
  margin: 20px 0 60px 0;
}

.quote p {
  font-style: italic;
}

.quote p:before {
  content: '“';
  font-size: 50px;
  opacity: .15;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 3px;
}

.quote p:after {
  content: '”';
  font-size: 50px;
  opacity: .15;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -42px;
  right: 3px;
}

.quote footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  right: 0;
}

.quote footer img {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.quote footer a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 30px;
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
}

.learn-bar>.learn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 272px;
  top: 8px;
  left: -300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

@media (min-width: 899px) {
  .learn-bar {
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 300px;
  }
  .learn-bar>.learn {
    left: 8px;
  }
}

.destroy {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/todomvc-common/base.css"> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/todomvc-app-css/index.css"> -->

<section class="todoapp">
  <header class="header">
    <h1>todos</h1>
    <input class="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus>
  </header>
  <!-- This section should be hidden by default and shown when there are todos -->
  <section class="main">
    <input id="toggle-all" class="toggle-all" type="checkbox">
    <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
    <ul class="todo-list">
      <!-- These are here just to show the structure of the list items -->
      <!-- List items should get the class `editing` when editing and `completed` when marked as completed -->
      <li class='completed'>
        <div class="view">
          <input class="toggle" checked type="checkbox">
          <label>Taste JavaScript</label>
          <button class="destroy"></button>
        </div>
        <input class="edit" value="Taste JavaScript">
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="view">
          <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
          <label>Refactoring Code</label>
          <button class="destroy"></button>
        </div>
        <input class="edit" value="Refactoring Code">
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="view">
          <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
          <label>Rewrite app to react</label>
          <button class="destroy"></button>
        </div>
        <input class="edit" value="Rewrite app to react">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <!-- This footer should hidden by default and shown when there are todos -->
  <footer class="footer">
    <!-- This should be `0 items left` by default -->
    <span class="todo-count"><strong>0</strong> item left</span>
    <!-- Remove this if you don't implement routing -->
    <ul class="filters">
      <li>
        <a class="selected" href="#/all">All</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/active">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/completed">Completed</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Hidden if no completed items are left ↓ -->
    <button class="clear-completed">Clear completed</button>
  </footer>
</section>
<footer class="info">
  <p>Double-click to edit a todo</p>
  <p>Enter to add/edit task</p>

</footer>
<!-- Scripts here. Don't remove ↓ -->
<!-- <script src="node_modules/todomvc-common/base.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: Если пишете и читаете на английском, можно ещё здесь спросить: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Спасибо большое, не знал про данный сервис

Comment: данный код работает? Выполняет указанную задачу?

Comment: какая часть кода написана тобой, а какая взята с http://todomvc.com/ ?

Comment: Писать на на нативном DOM API имело смысл, чтобы просто понять, какие возможности он предоставляет (createElement,addEventListener,...). Логику приложения оптимально писать на React, и она там сильно отличается: там мы не меняем хтмл по событиям, а меняем данные, и описываем зависимость хтмл-я от данных.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, в любой программе меняются данные и описаны зависимости html от данных

Comment: @Grundy, Можно писать в стиле: "когда кликнули -- добавить ряд в таблицу", а можно "когда кликнули -- добавить задачу ... каждой задаче соответствует ряд"

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, не вижу разницы

Comment: @Grundy, разница в том, что во втором случае легче поддерживать непротиворечивость; пример без хтмл: `a=1; b=a*2; ... a=3` vs `a=1; b=()=>a*2; ... a=3` -- нам надо помнить, что если мы меняем `a`, мы должны менять `b`; vs `b()` всегда в 2 раза больше

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, какой-то непонятный пример

Comment: @Grundy, я плохо написал в одну строку; или всё понятно, но опять "не видно разницы"? В первом случае `b` переменная, я знаю, что она должна быть в 2 раза больше `a`, и должен помнить, что ее надо пересчитать, если `a`, поменялась (и если их 30 штук, я забуду). Во втором варианте я просто говорю, что `b()` -- функция, и если `a` поменять, и вызвать `b()`, то результат просто будет в 2 раза больше `a`. [я спать]

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, и как это связано с "логику оптимально писать на реакт" - и без него можешь вынести операции в функции и вызывать их

Comment: @Grundy, 1) я могу и на ассемблере писать формы, только зачем. 2) Реакт -- один из способов описать содержимое DOM-элемента функцией, коротко и достаточно эффективно. 3) пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171553/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f/1172886#1172886

Comment: @Grundy, суть в одной картинке: https://medium.com/@jamessilvester/differences-between-jquery-and-react-3eaca58df34f

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, пример по ссылке - прям вообще не очень выглядит - как будто минификатором прошлись - непонятно что с чем связано и вообще что происходит. Пример с картинкой тож не очень - потому что и на jquery можно писать централизованно, и на react - лапшой (что в принципе и показано в примере по ссылке)

Comment: @Grundy, где там лапша? это шаблон, и кода 3 строчки. На jquery тоже можно написать функцию render, но: 1) обычно пишут как на картинке 2) будет (скорее всего) и кода больше 3) будет (возможно) работать медленней.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, ну тут нужно конкретные примеры разбирать. обычно и на react пишут не очень, размер кода - вообще слабый показатель, а уж скорость работы - вообще нужно замерять